# ASP Net Teams Tab Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, tabs, microsoft-teams

I have a ASP.net WebApp as a teams tab in Teams, I want to be able to authenticate in AAD. Can the JS examples be used to then secure parts of the .Net WebApp?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please look at [Authenticate a user in a Microsoft Teams tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/auth-tab-aad) documentation?

Here is how you could initiate authentication in Tab:

```
microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate({
    url: window.location.origin + "/tab-auth/simple-start",
    width: 600,
    height: 535,
    successCallback: function (result) {
        getUserProfile(result.accessToken);
    },
    failureCallback: function (reason) {
        handleAuthError(reason);
    } });
```

Here is complete sample code: [microsoft-teams-sample-auth-node](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-auth-node)